# How to create view model for display?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the model like this:

```
create_table "user_accounts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "code"
  t.string   "user_name"
  t.integer  "user_type",  :default => 1
end
```

the controller's code like this:

```
def index
  @user_accounts = UserAccount.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @user_accounts }
    format.xml { render :xml => @user_accounts }
  end
end
```

The View's code like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><%= t :code %></th>
    <th><%= t :user_name %></th>
    <th><%= t :user_type %></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @user_accounts.each do |user_account| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
    <td><%= user_account.code %></td>
    <td><%= user_account.user_name %></td>
    <td><%= user_account.user_type %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_account %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_account_path(user_account) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_account, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Everything works fine. but there is a flaw that the 'user_type' displayed as a number. but i  hope it can display as string like 'normal user' or 'system admin'.

The most important thing that I DON'T want to add any logic in the view(index.html.erb).

So what i need is to change the user_type's value at the controller or wherever.

there must be some elegant ways to do it. But i don't know.Hope you guys can give me some suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You don't want even a function in the view that will take in argument the user type and returns the correspondant stirng ?

Comment: yes, i don't want to add any logic in the view. For the best practice of MVC, View should be logic-free. So I hope it can happened in the controller or model layer.

Comment: The use of a view helper class would be appropriate in this case. Pushing 'view-related presentation logic' into the model class isn't always the ideal -- which is why helpers exist in rails. Is the use of a helper class something you're open to?

Comment: What u said is really exact.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to you model UserAccount some function like this

```
def user_type_string
    case self.user_type
    when 1
       return "Super user"
    when 2
       return "Something else"
    else
    end
end
```

And this method you can use in the view

```
<td><%= user_account.user_type_string %></td>
```

Comment: apart from this or any other solution, is there anything like viewmodels in rails?
for instance i have a table which have FK from 2 tables, and i want to display just a username field and than search and populate its id myself, and for other fk i want to display a list of something and than add key myself from logic. Is there anything like viemodel like in .net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have it defined as a number:

```
 t.integer  "user_type",  :default => 1
```

So you need to either define it as the string you want to present, or have logic that converts it.

I'd recommend creating a `/app/helpers/user_accounts_helper.rb` file like so:

```
module UserAccountsHelper

  def account_type_display(account_type)
    // put logic here to convert the integer value to the string you want to display
  end

end
```

Then change the line in your view file that presents the account type to:

```
   <td><%= account_type_display(user_account.user_type) %></td>
```

That should work.

Comment: As mentioned above, he doesn't want that method.

Comment: I didn't see where he said using a view helper is what he didn't want. Can you point that out? He said he didn't want logic in the view - which is what this accomplishes. **This function is not in the view**.

Comment: If I understood his request, he considers the `account_type_display` call as a logic.

Comment: This is an almost classic application for a view helper. Calling that 'embedding logic in the view' is misleading and incorrect.

Comment: I totally agree. In his situation, I would put in place the solution you gave. For me, it's still clean.

Comment: Well, I downvoted the answer because it doesn't really answer the question as he doesn't want to "touch" the view. But, as I'm ok with your point view, I upvoted three sentences above ;)

Comment: There's no way to resolve this without making a change to the view -- even if only to rename the attribute from `account_type` to `account_type_string`. Moreover, it somehow implies that the answer is incorrect, when in this case it's better to explain to the OP that this is a perfectly acceptable solution -- and in some ways preferable even to adding code to the model or controller.

Comment: Sure. But, sometimes, the questions are simplified. I think that this is what he did. I think also that there is a (very) good reason why he doesn't want to modify the view and keep it in a "scaffoled" way.